# Copying values from Superclass to Subclass

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I have below super class.

### SuperOne.java

```
public class SuperOne{

  private String id;
  private String name;

  //public setter and getter methods


}
```

### SubOne.java

```
public class SubOne extends SuperOne{

 //To Do : SubOne has no extra fields.

}
```

I have below method:

```
public SubOne getData(String id){

      SuperOne data = someDao.getData(String id)

      // Now we have result in data . Now i need to convert data into SubOne and return.

  }
```

**SuperOne.java** has no constructor and is provided by third party which i cannot modify.But i can modify SubOne as it is my own.
**Please suggest me the best way to convert SuperOne into SubOne**.

Comment: It is recommended to use `interfaces` for this kind of designs.

Comment: SuperOne.java is a pojo provided by third party which i cannot modify now.

Comment: Does `SuperOne` have public or protected `getId()` and `getName()` methods?  If they're protected you'll have to override them to make them public.

Comment: I dont have control over superOne and has all public methods.

Comment: Can you modify the data access layer? Are you using an ORM tool like Hibernate?

Comment: yeah did you check around the methods available in superOne??? for accessing the datamember.. methods would be there

Comment: I cannot modify someDao return type. It has to be super one.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to use option 2 from my answer below. If the database stores `SuperOne`, and the data layer returns `SuperOne`, then you don't have a `SubOne`, you have a `SuperOne`. You may wish to consider why you are doing what you are doing, there may be other options.

Comment: Because clients should not see the return type SuperOne. They have to get only SubOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SubOne` as a wrapper instead as a *child*.

```
class SubOne {

    private SuperOne superOne;

    public SubOne(SuperOne) {
        this.superOne = superOne;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.superOne.getId();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.superOne.getName();
    }

    public String setId(String id) {
        return this.superOne.setId(id);
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        return this.superOne.setName(name);
    }

    ///////////////

    public SubOne getData(String id){
        SuperOne data = someDao.getData(String id)
        return new SubOne(data);  
    }
```

#### Addendum

If you insist on inherit `SuperOne` you can do it like this.

```
class SubOne extends SuperOne {

    public SubOne(SuperOne superOne) {
        super.setId(superOne.getId());
        super.setName(superOne.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Basically my first paradigm usually is implemented with a declaration of an interface implemented by `SubOne` and `SuperOne`.

Comment: Outside of doing a full fledge field copy or using beanutils this is the best approach, though it does break hierarchy dependent implementations

Comment: Delegating is good, but inheriting at the same time creates unmaintainable code: when a new method gets added to `SuperOne`, calling that method on instances of `SubOne` will silently fail, and the user may have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Modify your data layer to read `SubOne` objects from the database instead of `SuperOne`.
2. Create a `SubOne` constructor that takes a `SuperOne` parameter and copies all of the data from it. This may break some internal invariants depending on ORM (for example, it could cause issues with Hibernate).
3. Give your `SubOne` a `SuperOne` field and assign that field to the object you read from the database. Override all public methods of `SuperOne` and delegate to the stored `SuperOne`. This may not be possible if there are `public final` methods of `SuperOne` that you cannot delegate.
4. Don't create a subclass. Create a new class with a `SuperOne` field and assign it to the object you read from the database. Add any extra high level logic to the new class. This may not be useful if you intend to pass your object to methods that expect a `SuperOne`.

Option 4 introduces the least amount of complications. Ask yourself if you truly need `SubOne` to be a subclass of `SuperOne`, or if you are just wrapping it with your own object and abstracting it away.

Comment: Jason, i feel 2nd option is suitable for me. What is the best way to copy super data inside sub constructor? Can u give me some snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Well if the data is private your subclass doesn't have access to it, unless `SuperOne` provides getters/setters (in which case you should use those). You could hack it with reflection but you might wish to consider other options, because it sounds like you are going down the wrong path. I have added two more options to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

No,You cant change the `Private` Data of an Parent class..

Is that against the OOPS concepts???

Comment: sam, i am not modifying the data. the data which is there in super class has to be populated into subclass and return the sub class. Thanks!